# The opposite of "exempt"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a word that fits in the same form, for example:

> Steve is exempt from the tax

To say the opposite I would need to say

> Steve is obligated to pay the tax.

I would like to be replace "is obligated to pay" with one or two words (plus preposition), to say:

> Steve is ____ the tax.

My searches for antonyms in Thesauruses didn't satisfy me.

Comment: There is also the phrase: "liable to tax". UK courts distinguished between its meaning and that of "subject to tax", as explained here: http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/community/blogs/paul-eaves/interpretation-of-double-tax-treaty-meaning-of-subject-to-tax-tc02178

Answer (score 10):

The opposite of *exempt from* is *subject to*:

> Steve is *subject to* the tax.

Comment: I like this word, but I would rather that the *person* were not subject to tax.  I'd rather that Steve's *income* were subject to tax.

Comment: Yes indeed @aparente001 - Steve is *liable* for tax.  His *income* is subject to tax.